# Meaning of the "Ten Green Bottle Jobs" headline in The Sun

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, slang

I don't understand what "green bottle" means in this newspaper. Could you explain? "Ten" is Man Utd's couch.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

"to bottle" means to fail or screw up. A "bottle job" means failing your mission. So the players failed; they wore green; there were 10 of them and the manager is named Ten (pun).

This is a British tabloid headline. There's a lot to unpack, it doesn't always make logical sense, and there's a lot of slang and double meaning.

Comment: There is a well known children's "counting" song ["Ten green bottles"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Green_Bottles)